# Checking if form already exists

Tags: javascript

Is there a better command than this to check if a form is exists and if so submit it? Right now I'm using:

```
if(document.forms[0])document.forms[0].submit()
```

Which works, however if form[0] does not exist it throws an exception. I'm trying to keep this dynamic in the sense I don't know what the form ID or name is.

Comment: If the problem is in JavaScript - I would not even tag this question as WP7

Comment: document.forms[0] is brittle, there can be more than 1 form on a page, and if the html changes your javascript is broken.  that's why i propose using Ids on the form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid the exception you could do:

```
if (typeof document.forms[0] !== 'undefined') document.forms[0].submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

can you add an id to the form?  can you use jquery?

with id, no jquery

```
var form = document.getElementById('my-form');
if (form != null) {
 form.submit();
}
```

with id & jquery

```
if ($("#my-form").length == 1) {
  $("#my-form").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for [`undefined`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp) :

```
if(document.forms[0] != 'undefined')
    document.forms[0].submit()
```

Answer (score 2):

If your only requirement is to check whether a form exists, and if so, submit the first form, you can use:

```
if (document.forms.length) document.forms[0].submit();
```